# On hostinger i have swapped the server to Spigot, but when i attempt start the server i get an error saying the spigot jar is nonexistent

Tags: server, hosting, minecraft, spigot

On hostinger i have swapped the server to Spigot, but when i attempt start the server i get an error saying the spigot jar is nonexistent
help
[server settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt73k.png)
[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlDhc.png)

i expected there would be no errrors but what happened was the spigot jar was missing. I tried contacting Hostinger support but they told me to come here as this is a "professional" technical issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to delete the server and initializing again, it might solve your issue.